# Replacement for pa_alsa_linux.h and pa_jack.h with pipewire

Tags: alsa, pulseaudio, audacity, jack, pipewire

I'm running Pop_OS 22.04 (which has pipewire audio) and audacity is hanging on launch (unless it is launch with sudo, which seems quite odd).

To try and debug the system, I'm trying to build audacity from github sources.

In the initial configuration phase of the build, I get the following messages

```
-- Fixing up ZLib mess...
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Looking for pa_jack.h
-- Looking for pa_jack.h - not found
-- Looking for pa_linux_alsa.h
-- Looking for pa_linux_alsa.h - not found
```

So, here is the thing I am confused about.  I thought that pipewire was API compatible with pulse-audio.  So shouldn't there be a version of the `pa_*.h` files to use with pipewire?  If so, which Debian package do I need to install to get them?

Answer (score 0):

The `pa_` stands for PortAudio, not pulse-audio.  The `portaudio19-dev` package had the required header files.